# Iterating Mongoengine queryset - how to prevent big memory consumption

Tags: python, mongodb, memory, orm, mongoengine

In my deployment environment I am trying to run a script with a loop similar to the one below.
However, the script get killed because it eats too much memory.
When I checked the loop for memory consumption, I noticed that on each iteration of the loop the consumption grows by 1-2MB.

Can someone advise what is the reason for such growing consumption and how can I prevent it?

```
import tracemalloc

from mongoengine_models import SomeModel

tracemalloc.start()
for count, rel in enumerate(SomeModel.objects.filter(some_attr="some_value")):
    current, peak = tracemalloc.get_traced_memory()
    current_mb = current / 10**6
    peak_mb = peak / 10**6
    print(f"Current memory usage is {current_mb}MB; Peak was {peak_mb}MB")
    print(count, rel.some_other_attr_1, rel.some_other_attr_2)
tracemalloc.stop()
```

UPDATE: I figured out I can prevent the growing consumption by doing `del rel`, `del some_other_attr_1`, `del some_other_attr_2` at the end of each iteration, by it feels like a hacky solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The results from the queryset are cached. You can avoid this by using `no_cache()`

```
SomeModel.objects.no_cache().filter(some_attr="some_value")
```

There is a post about no_cache [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53588542/the-effect-of-no-cache-on-queryset-in-mongoengine).